# Strategy for sending updates to a view while performing a large operation

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, view

This might be a very easy one for many of you - but I'm stuck trying to figure out a strategy for rendering updates to the View while server is performing a timeconsuming operation.

This is the case. I have a view that has a button which say "Approve". This approve needs to call some Action or backgroundprogress of some kind to perform a heavy operation that might take 20-30 seconds.

During that time I want to update the View with some kind of processing gif-animation and append text's like "performing operation A", "performing operation B" and so on.

What is the best stragegy for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an answer you might not like: don't even bother trying to get some "progress updates" from the server.

Take a look at this task from the commercial point of view.  The purpose of providing some feedback is to give the user some warm and fuzzy feeling that they have not been forgotten and the task they have asked their computer to do has not been abandoned.  How much cost are you willing to incur delivering this feature?

The simplest such device is the humble progress bar.  Even though most experience users would not trust it to tell them *when* a task will finish they do still trust that if its moving *something* is happening.

My solution would be to post off an async operation to the server to kick the operation off.  Then show a progress bar that is entirely managed by javascript.  It starts of rapidly but slows down as it progresses such that it would never actually complete but does appear to be making some progress.  When the async operation completes briefly show the progress bar as reaching completion then remove it.

The cost of other solutions is much, much greater but the benefit over this approach is almost negligable if not actually negative, after all they are complex to implement and are more likely to go wrong.

Comment: I agree. The value of having this feedback is less than the cost. I might end up with using the Ajax.ActionLink feature to kick off the proces and displaying some kind of animation while the processing. Then finally overwrite a <div> section with a message "Operation complete" or something :)

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I haven't tried but I am willing to do it.

I think [SignalR](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322154/ASP-NET-MVC-SIngalR-and-Knockout-based-Real-time-U) could be a good try.

Comment: Please do. Looking forward to hearing your solution :) Like I commented on Anthonys post - this might be so complex that I'm not going to do it - but - hey - lets keep the discussion open and see if there are brilliant people that have brilliant solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

while this sounds good in theory, I would make this a background operation that then sends a notification to the user via email or sms when the task is done.

otherwise you need to

- setup a cache (not asp.net cache) on the server to store the current state of the long running process
- setup a js timer to poll the server
- update the ui with the current state stored in the cache.

not impossible, but a lot of moving parts.

Comment: Email or sms for an operation that takes 30 seconds?